# system calling with arguments and pipe

Tags: python, unix

i have a text in variable called myText, and I want to run command like this:

```
myText = "This is my text"    
call("echo" + myText + " | mail username -s subj")
```

it means that I want to echo the text in myText and pass is to mail command thru pipe. 
what is right way to do this ?

Comment: Does this code work? If not, what does it do? What have you researched?

Comment: Did you already do `from subprocess import call`? If so, all you're missing is to surround `myText` with quotes, like `call("echo '" + myText + "' | mail username -s subj")`

Answer (score 3):

You should have a look to os command such as popen that allows you to create a pipe to make processes communicate between each other.
Check out this [page](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html)

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
p1 = Popen(['echo', myText], stdout=PIPE)
p2 = Popen('mail', stdin=p1.stdout)
```

This should work.

Comment: and how this "mail username -s subj" should be written instead of 'mail' in `p2 = Popen('mail', stdin=p1.stdout)` ?

Comment: This is good but needs waits on p1 and p2 to let the processes complete.

Comment: @user2234234 - it would be `p2 = Popen(['mail', 'username', '-s', 'subj'], stdin=p1.stdout)`. This example calls mail directly, skipping an intermediate shell, so it needs to break each argument out into a list.